.nodeColor() not updating node color for 3d-force-graph
i am having trouble changing the node color for my visualization using 3d-force-graph.
<head>
    <style> body { margin: 0; } </style>
  
    <script src="//unpkg.com/3d-force-graph"></script>
    <!--<script src="../../dist/3d-force-graph.js"></script>-->
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="3d-graph"></div>
    
    <script type="importmap">{ "imports": { "three": "//unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js" }}</script>
    <script type="module">

        const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
        (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
          .jsonUrl('jsondata.json')
          .nodeColor('rgb(255, 255, 255)')
          .nodeLabel(node => `${node.name}`)
          .d3Force('link').distance(link => 1 / link.value * 30)
          
          
    </script>
  </body>


what do i need to change? i've tried clearing my browser's cache too but it still doesn't seem to update. here's the link to the library i am using: https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph

Replace 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' with 'white' or '#ffffff' in your .nodeColor() method

The documentation states that .nodeColor can take a string or function but it only seems to work for me when given a function .nodeColor(node => 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')

@Mark thank you so much, this worked!

To change the color of the nodes i think you should specify a function for the nodeColor parameter rather than using a static string. i took a peak and found that The library and it says you can use a string or function so maybe try using a function instead.
try changing the node color with this:
" .nodeColor(node => 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') "
this should work
